# Looking for solution for Android Activity leak with AccessibilityManager

Tags: android, android-memory

I am noticing a memory leak which is only exhibited on GT-N8000 and GT-N7000 series android devices.
In the devices it does so, it leaks all the activities in the app.

This seems unrelated to my code and im unable to decipher it.

Any idea?

Example:
Here the path to GC which is preventing the activity from garbage collecting. The activity is already dead. (seen via Eclipse Memory Analyzer).

```
mBase com.sample.MyActivity
   |- mContext android.widget.FrameLayout
   |- mContext com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneFallbackEventHandler
   |  '- mFallbackEventHandler android.view.ViewRootImpl
   |     '- this$0 android.view.ViewRootImpl$AccessibilityInteractionConnectionManager
   |        '- [0] java.lang.Object[43]
   |           '- elements java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList
   |              '- mAccessibilityStateChangeListeners android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager
   |                 |- sInstance class android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager
   |                 |- this$0 android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager$1
```

Comment: I take it you have done this analysis on other hardware, and it does not exhibit the same problem? Did those tests encompass the same Android OS version?

Comment: Looks like you're adding your Activity as an AccessibilityStateChangeListener and never removing it.

Comment: Appears to be only (or mostly) on 4.1.2.

Comment: Did you find the reason/solution?